# Converter uma string em inteiro no SQLite

Tags: sqlite3

Prezados estou tentando criar uma sql para um aplicativo móvel, a sql está tudo bem mas à aplicação dá o seguinte erro na hora de executar: *"campo esperando uma string e atual é inteiro"*, a pergunta é como faço para converter o campo "icone" da sql para inteiro, segue sql:

```
select
    l.*,
    c.descricao as categoria,
    case when l.tipo_lancamento = ‘c’ then 1 else 0 end as icone
from
    tab_lancamento l 
join
    tab_categoria c on (c.id_categoria = l.id_categoria)
```

O campo tipo_lancamento é um varchar mas, mas já mudei para um integer mas continua dando de de incompatibilidade

Desde já Agradeço!!!

Comment: Qual é o tipo do campo `tipo_lancamento` na tabela  `tab_lancamento` ? você poderia postar a estrutura das tabelas ?

Comment: O campo tipo_lancamento é um varchar mas, mas já mudei para um integer mas continua dando de de incompatibilidade

Comment: 1) Se o campo `tipo_lancamento` é um inteiro, qual o motivo de compara-lo com um `c` ? 2) Você parece estar usando uma espécie de acento agudo para delimitar o `c`, tente usar aspas simples.

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que sua Estrutura seja similar ao seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_lancamento
(
    id_lancamento integer,
    id_categoria integer,
    tipo_lancamento character varying(1)
);

CREATE TABLE tab_categoria
(
    id_categoria integer,
    descricao text
);
```

Dados:

```
INSERT INTO tab_categoria ( id_categoria, descricao ) VALUES ( 1, 'Primeira Categoria' );
INSERT INTO tab_categoria ( id_categoria, descricao ) VALUES ( 2, 'Segunda Categoria' );
INSERT INTO tab_categoria ( id_categoria, descricao ) VALUES ( 3, 'Terceira Categoria' );

INSERT INTO tab_lancamento ( id_lancamento, id_categoria, tipo_lancamento ) VALUES ( 1, 1, 'a' );
INSERT INTO tab_lancamento ( id_lancamento, id_categoria, tipo_lancamento ) VALUES ( 2, 2, 'c' );
INSERT INTO tab_lancamento ( id_lancamento, id_categoria, tipo_lancamento ) VALUES ( 3, 3, 'c' );
INSERT INTO tab_lancamento ( id_lancamento, id_categoria, tipo_lancamento ) VALUES ( 4, 1, 'a' );
INSERT INTO tab_lancamento ( id_lancamento, id_categoria, tipo_lancamento ) VALUES ( 5, 2, 'b' );
INSERT INTO tab_lancamento ( id_lancamento, id_categoria, tipo_lancamento ) VALUES ( 6, 3, 'c' );
```

A seguinte consulta deverá funcionar:

```
SELECT
    l.*,
    c.descricao AS categoria,
    (CASE WHEN l.tipo_lancamento = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS icone
FROM
    tab_lancamento l 
JOIN
    tab_categoria c ON ( c.id_categoria = l.id_categoria );
```

Saída:

```
id_lancamento  id_categoria  tipo_lancamento  categoria           icone     
-------------  ------------  ---------------  ------------------  ----------
1              1             a                Primeira Categoria  0         
2              2             c                Segunda Categoria   1         
3              3             c                Terceira Categoria  1         
4              1             a                Primeira Categoria  0         
5              2             b                Segunda Categoria   0         
6              3             c                Terceira Categoria  1
```